# power series of interval of convergence of [-1,1]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is there a power series whose interval of convergence is [-1, 1] and which is conditionally convergent both at $-1$ and $1$? .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $i$ be such that $i^2=-1$. Consider the following power series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n}nx^n.
$$ Then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n}n$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n}n(-1)^n$ are convergent by the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), and they are not absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^2/n.$